# When did Luke learn his father's first name?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, luke-skywalker

I've just rewatched *Star Wars Episode IV: A New Hope*, and I don't recall anyone mentioning Anakin by his first name. So my question is, when did Luke learn his father's first name, and who told him it, his uncle or someone else?

Comment: I would assume that at some point, he asked his aunt and uncle what his father's name was.  If he didn't, he'd be the least curious person ever.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just curious at what age.

Comment: Good first question.  You have my upvote. I'll be interested to see the answers.  You might find some clues on [this](http://starwarz.com/starkiller/) site

Answer (score 30, accepted):

***Within*** the main film canon, the first time Luke hears the name Anakin is during Ben's "*from a certain point of view, I'm not a huge liar*" speech on Dagobah during 'Return of the Jedi'.

> “You told me Darth Vader betrayed and murdered my father.” The
>   bitterness he’d felt earlier, with Yoda, had found its focus now on
>   Ben.
>
> Ben absorbed the vitriol undefensively, then padded it with
>   instruction. “Your father, **Anakin, was seduced by the dark side of the
>   Force—He ceased to be Anakin Skywalker, and became Darth Vader.** When
>   that happened, he betrayed everything that Anakin Skywalker believed
>   in. The good man who was your father was destroyed. So what I told you
>   was true … from a certain point of view.”
>
> “A certain point of view!” Luke rasped derisively. He felt betrayed—by
>   life more than anything else, though only poor Ben was available to
>   take the brunt of his conflict. “Luke,” Ben spoke gently, “you’re
>   going to find that many of the truths we cling to depend greatly on
>   our point of view.” - <sub>[Return of the Jedi - Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_VI:_Return_of_the_Jedi_(novel))</sub>

Note that it stands to reason that he already knew his father's name before this speech (presumably from Beru and Owen) but this is the first time that we hear Anakin's name in Luke's presence.

Comment: I knew you would be the one who answered this.  And I knew you'd use the novelization.  +1